# Debugging of the UI5 Expression Bindings

Tags: data-binding, sapui5

Is there any way to debug UI5 [Expression Bindings](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0) (without [Formatters](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/0f8626ed7b7542ffaa44601828db20de)), embedded into XML with DevTools/IDE, but not in SAP WebIDE?

Comment: you could try to write the debugger js statement hard into the expression, if that doesnt work try to put the code into a formatter for testing, in formatters you can set breakpoints directly in the browser as usual

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debug "parse" method of [`ExpressionParser`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/base/ExpressionParser.js) class. You can test that by creating a very simple app using the following code.

**View**

```xml
<App id="app">
    <pages>
        <Page id="page" title="{i18n>title}">
            <content>
                <Text text="{= ${/a} + ${/b} }" />
            </content>
        </Page>
    </pages>
</App>
```

**Controller**

```js
onInit: function () {
    var oModel = new JSONModel({
        a: 2,
        b: 3
    });

    this.getView().setModel(oModel);
}
```

In DevTools, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open a file by searching for its name — `ExpressionParser`. If not, you can find this file in the following path (see image below): `/resources/sap/ui/base/ExpressionParser-dbg.js`

[image: DevTools]

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I don't find `ExpressionParser.js` in the list of the downloaded files in the DevTools.